# Difference of Two numbers - BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am just trying to learn more about BigDecimal, but below code makes me confuse.

```
Double x = 1.2;
String y = "1.2";

BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.ZERO;

a = new BigDecimal(x);
b = new BigDecimal(y);

int res = res = b.compareTo(a);

if(res==1){
    System.out.println("Die");
}else if(res ==0){
    System.out.println("Live");
}else if (res==-1){
    System.out.println("God Loves you");
}
```

> Result = Die

I am not ready to "**Die**", why BigDecimal is hell bent on killing me.

Comment: Philip, So when I asked I am not ready to Die, I meant,  shouldn't the result be "live" as both values are equal rather than Die.

Comment: I think it's absolutely clear what the question is.

Comment: Don't use `Double` when you can use `double`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This statement:

```
Double x = 1.2;
```

assigns the *nearest `double`-representable value* to 1.2 to `x`. That's just *less* than 1.2 - the value 1.2 itself can't be represented exactly in binary.

Now when you create a `BigDecimal` from that value, that "not quite 1.2" value is retained exactly. From the constructor's documentation:

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value.

... whereas when you use `new BigDecimal("1.2")` the result is *exactly* 1.2 - `BigDecimal` parses the string, and any decimal string representation *can* be represented exactly by `BigDecimal`, as that's the whole point of it.

1.2 is slightly bigger than "the nearest `double` representation of 1.2" hence `res` is 1.

Comment: Thank you Sir for clearing my doubt. but that raised another one, Why the hell did they create "Float or Double" in the first place? Should I first convert Double to String and then to Big Decimal?

Comment: float take less memory (32bit) than double (64)

Comment: float represents a standard IEEE floating point representation.

Comment: @SJagdeesh: You should think carefully before converting `double` to `BigDecimal` *at all*. It's very rarely a good idea. What's your use case? Often this sort of thing suggests that you should be using `BigDecimal` earlier on, and avoid `double` entirely.

Comment: I was just playing around with BigDecimal. I also have seen in many cases while integration of different modules developed by different developers, These kind of problems arise when we try to calculate something or put some condition check.

Comment: +1 Or use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` to use the value double would print as.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Wow - hadn't spotted that. It feels like an easy-to-miss difference :(

Answer (score 2):

```
a = new BigDecimal(x); // a= 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
b = new BigDecimal(y); // b=1.2
```

This is due to conversion issue since translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation.

```
int res = res = b.compareTo(a); //res= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `1.2` as double [is not what you expect it to be](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(x));
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(y);
```